# Injecting token received from anticaptcha for recaptcha v2 using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

I am using [anticaptcha](https://anti-captcha.com/) to help out with bypassing recaptcha on a webpage I'm crawling.

I have managed to work out the api part of this solution. It's quite straightforward.
The part I am struggling with is the injection of the token received from anti-captcha into the webpage.

Haven't found too many resources on this. I am using `Selenium` and `Python` alongside the `anticaptchaofficial` module.

The script I am executing does change the innerHtml of the `textarea` with id `g-recaptcha-response` but the webpage does nothing and the checkbox doesn't load the spinner or get verified.
Here's my code:

```
from anticaptchaofficial.recaptchav2proxyless import recaptchaV2Proxyless

from selenium import webdriver

import os
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd()+"\\chromedriver.exe"))
driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
time.sleep(1)

data_sitekey = driver.find_element_by_class_name('g-recaptcha').get_attribute('data-sitekey')

solver = recaptchaV2Proxyless()
solver.set_verbose(1)
solver.set_key("<--my-key-->")
solver.set_website_url("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
solver.set_website_key(data_sitekey)

g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()

driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}";'.format(g_response)) # target textarea that is supposed to be injected with the token, I found upon some research
driver.execute_script("onSuccess('{}')".format(g_response))
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was under the assumption that the recaptcha frame would show visible feedback on injection of the token (or some other equivalent action) but it turns out just the line:

`driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}";'.format(g_response))`

which updates the textarea's innerHtml is enough. So you would basically need to continue with your task ie: click submit, if it is a recaptcha on form or reload the page if it is just randomly triggered

```
from anticaptchaofficial.recaptchav2proxyless import recaptchaV2Proxyless

from selenium import webdriver

import os
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd()+"\\chromedriver.exe"))
driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
time.sleep(1)

data_sitekey = driver.find_element_by_class_name('g-recaptcha').get_attribute('data-sitekey')

solver = recaptchaV2Proxyless()
solver.set_verbose(1)
solver.set_key("<--my-key-->")
solver.set_website_url("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
solver.set_website_key(data_sitekey)

g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()

driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}";'.format(g_response)) 

time.sleep(1)

# whatever the next step is. Could be clicking on a submit button
driver.refresh()
```